# Does an element contain a specified string (pure JS)?

Tags: javascript, string

Given this:

```
<p>knownString-randomString</p>
```

How do I find all paragraphs in a document that contain "knownString-," using pure JavaScript only?

For each instance of `<p>knownString-randomString</p>`, I need to split "knownString-randomString" at the hyphen(`-`) and store "randomString" in a variable for later use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get your elements

   var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

2. For loop with check and split your string

```
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
   if(paragraphs[i].innerHTML.search('knownString') > -1){
       randomString = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.split('-')[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: You should be searching for `knownString-`...`randomString` will be random so you may not have that..

Comment: This did exactly what I needed to do. Thanks, Philipp!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
function FindRandomStrings()
{
    var allParagraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var regex = /knownString-(.*)/;
    var result = [];
    var match;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++)
    {
        match = regex.exec(allParagraphs[i].innerHTML);

        if (match)
        {
            result.push(match[1]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your paragraphs are inside some other element, either a div, or ultimately the `<body>`, you can select those with jQuery $('divID p'), iterate through them, and use split() to separate the known and unknown strings into an array.

```
var ArrayElement = split("knownString-randomString");
```

ArrayElement(0) will have your knownString, and ArrayElement(1) will have your randomString.

Comment: Kirby, I'd like to use a pure JavaScript solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomStrings = [];
var ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    if(ps[i].textContent.startsWith('knownString')) {
        randomStrings.push(ps[i].textContent.split('-')[1]);
    }
}
```

The variables you need would be stored in `randomStrings`

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the desired string into a regular expression.
- Retrieve all paragraphs (modified as desired using `querySelectorAll` selectors).
- Iterate through all the paragraphs.
- For each paragraph, get the text and search it with the regular expression.
- If there is a match, add it to an accumulating list of "hits".

```js
var knownString = "knownString";
var regex = new RegExp(knownString + "\\-(.*)");
var pars = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var results = [];
[].forEach.call(pars, function(par) {
  var x = par.firstChild.nodeValue.match(regex);
  if (x) results.push(x[1]);
});
alert(results);
```

```html
<p>something else</p>
<p>knownString-randomString1</p>
<p>knownString-randomString2</p>
```